# Reference drawable image titled as a number

Tags: android, drawable

Can you reference a drawable if the file name is simply a number?

> Example: If I have an image name "1.jpg" in res/drawable it will give me an error if I try to reference it using R.drawable.1
>
> If I have an image name "one.jpg" in res/drawable it will work fine if I try to reference it using R.drawable.one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: **No.**

Longer answer:

The filename of every included resource is used in packaging - it will be assigned as the field name for a `public static final int` in the R.java file. This means that resource names, among other restrictions, must also satisfy the conditions for Java variable names.

Note what [one of the Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) reminds us about Java variable naming:

> A variable's name can be any legal identifier — an unlimited-length sequence of Unicode letters and digits, beginning with a letter, the dollar sign "$", or the underscore character "_".

So the following are valid Java variable names and will compile:

```
public static final int _1=0x7f020000;
public static final int one=0x7f020001;
```

While the following variable name would cause a compilation error:

```
public static final int 1=0x7f020000;
```

The long answer is that this is existing behavior in java that Android has built upon, retaining the same restrictions.

Additionally, it goes further: R.java is not specific to drawables. You will notice that you cannot have a `1.xml` layout or even a `<string name="1">` in your `strings.xml` file.

Comment: Thanks, I came to conclusion that this may be the reason why. It makes sense, just as with naming conventions with variables in Java. :-)